# How to map a component with the Id in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to map my company's business objects (xml not annotation), which have the following general structure:

```
ObjectDetail        (main table)
    ObjectSummary   (main table)
        objectId
    otherStuffInMainTable
    otherStuffInOtherTables
```

I know how to map the Summary with a simple Id, and I know how to map the Summary object as a component of the Detail object, but I'm not sure how to tell the Detail object that its Id is in a component.  There's a lot of information in the Hib Docs about embeddable Ids, but it's all about multi-column keys.  I have a simple Id, but I don't want to use the syntax they suggest because just the Id in Summary is the table key, not the whole Summary object.

Is there any best-practice for this that I'm just missing, or any good ideas out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `ObjectSummary.objectId` is also the id for `ObjectDetail`, they should be mapped to a single table. In this case, `ObjectSummary` can't be a an entity, with a "life cycle" that is independent from `ObjectDetail`.

You can mark `ObjectSummary` as an embeddable entity. `ObjectDetail` will have a property embedding `ObjectSummary`. Check the documentation for the section about [embeddable objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-component).

Comment: Thanks, objectId is indeed the Id for both objects.  And I do need to access them independently (I need to query Summaries, although I don't need to update them).  But you haven't actually answered my question:  I know about components/embedded objects, but Hibernate requires that ObjectDetail has an Id, and the Id is a single field inside ObjectSummary.  There's an annotation EmbeddableId that looks like it's the right idea, but that makes the entire ObjectSummary into the Id, and I just want a simple Integer inside ObjectSummary to be the key.  Thanks!

Comment: This question became defunct, but there are no other answers, and I can see that this is one way of handling separate querying of Summary and Detail, so I'm accepting.